# Integration Logic Apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, power-automate

Apologies if this is not the right place to ask but I have a burning question. My company currently has the following integration in place:

Cloud application 1 <-SOAP Web Service-> Biztalk Server IaaS <-Azure Service Bus or SFTP (depending on the message size)-> Cloud Application 2

Can we replace Biztalk Server and SOAP Web Service currently hosted in Biztalk Server with Logic Apps or even Microsoft Flow?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the details, but in Logic Apps you have:

-Integration Account to manage your schemas and maps, as in BizTalk
- ServiceBus and SFTP connectors
- Expose as a SOAP service requirement, you can use API Management

Then without the details, obviously you could replace.